# Using SQLite Python and Multithreading

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm desperately trying to get this code to work from about 70 threads, where it won't be run exactly at the same time, but pretty closely. All I really want is a way of saying, try to insert this, and if you can't back off for a while and try again, just doit without breaking the database. I'm using no options when creating the database, except for the filename. The only problem is I'm getting lots of **disk I/O errors** and **database disk image is malformed**. I'm trying to run this in a transaction, so if anything goes wrong it should roll back. I've tried the isolation_level=None option on the connection, which didn't really help. I'm using the Python sqlite3 module.

Here's the code

```
update_simulations_end_time_sql = """update simulations set end_time=?, completion_status =? where id=?;"""

def __set_time(sql_command, data):
    retries=0
    while retries<5:
        try:
            with create_tables.create_connection() as conn:
                cur = conn.cursor()
                cur.execute("begin")
                cur.execute(sql_command, data)
                return
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"__set_time has failed with {sql_command}")
            print(e)
            sleep_time = uniform(0.1,4)
            print(f"Sleeping for {sleep_time}")
            sleep(sleep_time)
            retries+=1
            
    raise Exception(f"__set_time failed after {retries}")
```

Here's the options sqlite was compiled with

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM pragma_compile_options;
COMPILER=gcc-9.4.0
ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA
ENABLE_DBSTAT_VTAB
ENABLE_FTS3
ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS
ENABLE_FTS3_TOKENIZER
ENABLE_FTS4
ENABLE_FTS5
ENABLE_JSON1
ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION
ENABLE_PREUPDATE_HOOK
ENABLE_RTREE
ENABLE_SESSION
ENABLE_STMTVTAB
ENABLE_UNKNOWN_SQL_FUNCTION
ENABLE_UNLOCK_NOTIFY
ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT
HAVE_ISNAN
LIKE_DOESNT_MATCH_BLOBS
MAX_SCHEMA_RETRY=25
MAX_VARIABLE_NUMBER=250000
OMIT_LOOKASIDE
SECURE_DELETE
SOUNDEX
THREADSAFE=1
USE_URI
```

If anyone has any ideas on how to solve this, I would be amazingly grateful.

Comment: Checking the threat safe mode: [sqlite3.threadsafety](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.threadsafety);

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.11 you will be able to use the sqlite3 module with options like ([link](https://ricardoanderegg.com/posts/python-sqlite-thread-safety/)):

```
import sqlite3

if sqlite3.threadsafety == 3:
    check_same_thread = False
else:
    check_same_thread = True

conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:", check_same_thread=check_same_thread)
```